# Передача переменных через FlashVars

Tags: flash

Собственно ворос как передать в SWF ролик переменную и отловить ее внутри.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При запуске, внутри добавленного на Stage спрайта:

```
var flashVars:Object = this.stage.loaderInfo.parameters as Object;
var localName:String = flashVars.value; (или flashVars["value"])
```

Если нужно в риалтайме из флеша:

```
var result = ExternalInterface.call("functionName", "param1", "param2", ...);
```

Для вызова из яваскрипта:

```
function callMe(name:String):String 
{ 
    return "busy signal"; 
} 
ExternalInterface.addCallback("myFunction", callMe);
```

Подробней о классе - [Документация Action Script 3 - ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

Живые примеры - [Статья 1](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/bridge-to-flash), [Статья 2](http://www.borshak.com/notes/18-03-2011.htm)

Comment: Заработало только вот так :
var flashVars = this.stage.loaderInfo.parameters as Object;
var localName:String = flashVars.value; (или flashVars["value"])

Comment: да, да, это я скопировал из проекта, а объявление переменной в шапке осталось :) поправил

Comment: есть еще такое уточнение :) Если не сложно опиши плз эту конструкцию this.stage.loaderInfo.parameters начиная с this. тоесть наследование откуда и куда =)

Comment: - this -> Класс DisplayObject (Sprite, Shape, MovieClip) или его наследник.
 - stage -> Свойство класса DisplayObject, становится доступным после его добавления в список отображения. (Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE)
 - loaderInfo - содержащий сведения о загрузке файла, к которому принадлежит этот экранный объект.
 - parameters -> Нетипизированный объект, список параметров зависит от нтмл контейнера или скрипта страницы. Полностью список можно смотреть дебагом.

Answer (score 1):

Я в свое время разбирался по [**этой**](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html) доке.